# Haskell from List of Pairs to Pair of Lists

Tags: haskell

I want to create a simple (involving sets and lists) function that can do the following, and i'm not sure where to start.

```
split:: [(a,b)] -> ([a],[b])
```

Comment: This already exists as the `Data.List.unzip` function

Comment: Type [that exact type](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=%5B(a%2Cb)%5D+-%3E+\(%5Ba%5D%2C%5Bb%5D\)) into Hoogle. Now you're done! =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's take it step by step. The two cases for the function are:

```
split [] = ???
split ((a,b):ps) = ???
```

One case is easy enough.

```
split [] = ([], [])
```

For the other one, we have to use the function recursively, someway

```
split ((a,b):ps) = ???? where
                    (as, bs) = split ps
```

I think it's easy to see that the solution is

```
split ((a,b):ps) = (a:as, b:bs) where
                     (as, bs) = split ps
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Guido's solution, there is more than one way to do it in haskell.

Please take a look at `fst` and `snd`, which takes the first / second element out of a pair, respectively.

```
GHCi> :t fst
fst :: (a, b) -> a
GHCi> :t snd
snd :: (a, b) -> b
```

You should be familiar with `map` if you are playing with functional programming languages, which takes a function and a list, applies the function on every element of that list, and gives you all the results in another list:

```
GHCi> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Given a list of pairs, you want two lists, one contains all first elements in order, and the other contains all second elements:

```
GHCi> let split xs = (map fst xs, map snd xs)
GHCi> split [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]
([1,3,5],[2,4,6])
GHCi>
```

One step further, as @jozefg has pointed out in the comment, that this method is not efficient as @Guido 's one, but we can make some changes to improve it (which is exactly what @Guido 's solution):

Now it's time to take a look at how `map` is implemented [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#map)

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ []     = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs
```

so we can try to change our `split` a little:

we still need the base case, (i.e. what if `xs` is empty):

```
split [] = ([], [])
split ls = (map fst ls, map snd ls) -- attention!
```

and we break the list into head and tail, just like `map`:

```
split (x:xs) = (fst x: map fst xs, snd x: map snd xs)
```

Now we can do a pattern matching, `(a,b) = x`, so we don't have to call two individual functions to break a pair into two:

```
split (x:xs) = (a: map fst xs, b: map snd xs)
    where (a,b) = x
```

Compare the code here with the line I commented "attention!", have you realized that if we know the result of `(map fst xs, map snd xs)`, we can simply reuse that result to speed up. Luckily, we already have `split ls = (map fst ls, map snd ls)`!

Using this fact, we finally come up with this version:

```
split [] = ([], [])
split (x:xs) = (a:as , b:bs)
    where (a,b)   = x
          (as,bs) = split xs
```

So there are essentially the same! (but as you can see, the last version we have is more efficient.)

Comment: This traverses the list twice though, something to keep in mind.

Comment: @jozefg I admit that, just thought it's easier to come up with and let `map` handle the recursion part.

Comment: @Guido despite the efficiency, essentially we are doing the same thing! just updated my answer :)

Comment: @Javran, of course, but yours really brings up reasoning by composing functions. Which is one of the main ideas of FP.

Comment: @Guido I'm wondering if the compiler is smart enough to do the optimization. Ideally we love to reuse functions and trust that the compiler will try its best.

Comment: A higher-order composition version that only need one traversal would be `foldr (\(a,b) (as,bs) -> (a:as, b:bs) ) ([],[])`.